# Tools needed to unmount bike pedals

Tags: pedals, lubricant

My two pedals are squeaking a bit and probably need to be lubricated. But, I'm not sure which tools I need to buy to unmount them.

What's the size of the square drive sockets to get to unmount the pedals? After googling the pedal size I see that the majority are 9/16", but the square bits are usually in mm. Is 14mm the right size?
I suppose an adjustable wrench will also prove useful to remove the pedals from the crankset. Is there another component needed for that?

Below is a small picture of the pedal in question:

[image: Pedals]

Comment: Usually it is a 15 mm narrow key for the pedals, but most pedals never have to be taken of to be oiled. (Comment and not an answer as I am not sure it is universal.)

Comment: Be aware the left hand pedal is a left hand thread.

Comment: @Willeke I was asking because one of the pedals was taken off by somebody I know, degreased and then lubricated. Now it rotates without  friction. I'm not sure how to apply the lube to the other pedal's bearing without removing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't need to remove to oil these pedals.

Lean your bike over to the side, pedal facing to ground.

Run oil down the pedal shaft into the pedal bearing - spin the pedal on the shaft, and the oil will wick into the gap between the metal and the plastic. 
More oil until it is free and quiet. A thickish oil -  wet-ride ride chainlube, Chainsaw oil, or thin motor oil is probably ideal.

Put (thin) oil on the thread end of the pedal shaft, hoping it will wick in (back side of the crank arm), this helps keep it from rusting up for when you do need to remove it.

---

If you actually need to remove them

Usually 15mm, and you might need a longish spanner or extension the first time, as shops tend to assemble them dry, and they seize up.

Left hand pedal is a left hand (backwards) thread.

Put it back in with lots of grease on the thread, so it won't seize for next time.

Comment: Does the pedal need to be degreased with WD40 before lubricating it?

Comment: No. Just add oil. Regularly - when you oil the chain

Answer (score 3):

Look on the inside of the crankarms, where the pedal threads into the crankarm, if there is a socket for a hex wrench. Cheaper pedals don't and I'm guessing these don't.

Pedals require a narrow spanner, as indicated by *Willeke*, thus an ordinary adjustable wrench ... could work but probably won't. Google around for `pedal spanners` to see how the professional ones look like.

Lastly, I once again agree with *Willeke* to try and oil them in place. Even if you removed them, disassembling a pedal can be a challenging and tool-requiring business.

Answer (score 3):

The Park Tool pedal wrench has 15mm and 9/16" sides, so I guess yours will be one of these sizes.

An adjustable wrench might work, but often the flats on the pedal spindle are not wide enough.

After you get the pedals off you have to figure out how to service the bearings. Pedal bearings are not standardized in any way, so you should proceed with caution.

Comment: More recent pedals may require an 8mm hex key to remove.

Comment: More recent expensive pedals. (Not the ones I need to replace soon.)